# In dataframe repeat words in a column X number of times as indicated in column y

Tags: r

I have one column with words (x) and one with numbers (y). I would like to create a third column (z) where the words are repeated the number of times indicated in column y.

Example data:

```
 x <- c("one", "two", "three")
 y <- c(1, 2, 3)
 df <- data.frame(x, y)
```

This is the preferred end result:

```
 z <- c("one", "two two", "three three three")
 df <- data.frame(x, y, z)

       x y                 z
 1   one 1               one
 2   two 2           two two
 3 three 3 three three three
```

I have tried:

```
df$z <- rep(df$x, df$y)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `strrep`

```
with(df, strrep(x, y))
```

which gives an output without a space, but if we need a space, then `paste` a space at the end of the string in 'x', do the `strrep` and remove the extra space at the end with `trimws`

```
df$z <- with(df, trimws(strrep(paste(x, ' '), y)))
df$z
#[1] "one"                 "two  two"            "three  three  three"
```